# Task Trigger (after Insert , after update)

Tags: apex, trigger, tasks

Purpose :

To update Field 1 which is not present in UI with Field 2 which is present in UI

```
 trigger  UpdateField1 on Task (after insert, after update) {
 List<Task> tasksToUpdate = new List<Task>();
Set<Id> TaskIds = new Set<Id>();
    for (Task task: Trigger.new){
        TaskIds.add(task.id);
    }
 List<Task> taskList = [SELECT Id, Field1, Field2 , RecordType.Name 
                                         FROM Task WHERE Id IN:TaskIds];

    for (Task taskRecord :taskList ){
       if(taskRecord.RecordType.Name == 'Communication Task' && taskRecord.Field1!= Date.ValueOf(taskRecord.Field2)){

            taskRecord.Field1 = Date.ValueOf(taskRecord.Field2);

            tasksToUpdate.add(taskRecord);

        }  
    }
if (!tasksToUpdate.isEmpty()){
        update tasksToUpdate;
}

}
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Please edit your original post to include more details about what you are trying to do and what is not working.

Answer (score 0):

This design pattern results in a recursive update, which will be broken by the system, since it cannot determine if this update will result in an infinite loop ("the record XYZ is already in a DML operation and cannot be updated" or some such error will be reported).

Instead, use the before insert/before update trigger event, and start from there.

```
trigger  UpdateField1 on Task (after insert, after update) {
    Id communicationTaskRTId = Task.SObjectType.getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfosByName()
        .get('Communication Task').getRecordTypeId();
    for(Task record: Trigger.new) {
        if(record.RecordTypeId == communicationTaskRTId && 
                record.Field1 != Date.valueOf(record.Field2)) {
            record.Field1 = Date.valueOf(record.Field2);
        }
    }
}
```

In a before insert/before update trigger context, any changes to the records in Trigger.new will be committed to the database during the initial "save" that occurs after this trigger event, so there is no need for a DML statement to persist the change.

Comment: Thank sfdc for the inputs . I have created the before trigger with your logic . This seems to  work correctly from desktop but in mobile the user input field is not getting updated and hence both the fields are coming up as blank . Any thing I am missing for mobile ?